# How can I autoselect the first option in Twitter typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

Please note that this is for Twitter typeahead.js which is not the same as boostrap typeahead (which has been removed from Bootstrap in 3.0)

According to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/32) the feature has been added, but I can not see how to implement it.

I have tried

```
autoselect: 'first'
```

and

```
autoselect: true
```

Neither seems to work.

Comment: The feature is not merged into master branch on github yet, it's scheduled for v0.10.0 and available at this branch: https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js/tree/32-enter-autoselect

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're using the [latest release](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) (>[v0.10.0](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/releases/tag/v0.10.0)). This feature was merged into the master branch on Feb 2, 2014. Here's how you would initialize a typeahead with the `autoselect: true` option:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  autoselect: true
},
{
  name: 'my-dataset',
  source: mySource
});
```

For more, check out the documentation on [initializing the typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheadoptions-datasets) and the [`autoselect` option](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options).

Comment: Would be really nice to have, but doesn't work for me (tried with v0.10.2). Also, the documentation you linked does not mention the `autoselect` option.
Had to to come up with my own hack for that...

Comment: It works for me. The first item is NOT highlighted as you type but it will be selected when you hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly couldn't make autoselect option work, besides I needed to implement it in a way that it autoselects the first option ONLY IF I HAD ONE RESULT from the source.

This worked for me:

```
...
success: function(data) {
                        process(data);
                        if (data[0] != null) {
                            $(".tt-dropdown-menu .tt-suggestion").trigger("click"); //autoselect the first element.
                        }
                    }
...
```

Comment: This lead me in the right direction for a solution, just note it's not a drop in solution for newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is an autoSelect option that about to be merged to master. You can clone the requester's repo and use it immediately (working great for me).

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/1356

https://github.com/hongz1/typeahead.js

Answer (score 0):

I used a dirty trick, I just added empty element as First Item, works like a charm...

```
var typeaheadSource = [{ id: 0, firstName: " | | "}, <?php print $product_list; ?>];
```

Which look like this...

```
var typeaheadSource = [{ id: 0, firstName: " | | "}, { id: 1, firstName: "Coca Cola 1.5L | 9555589200415 | 0.00"}];
```

In my case I'm populating the data in PHP.

You may wanna do some checking in the onSelect event, if it requires in your case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on version 0.11.1 for ajax requests to autoselect the first option, only when 1 result is returned

The code hooks the return from the ajax request, if the return is only 1 item it will tell the typeahead the request failed ( preventing the list from opening ) and manually set the result

```
const $field = $( '#auto_complete' );

const bloodhound = new Bloodhound( {
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: `remoteUrl?&q=%QUERY`, // Set the proper URL...
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        rateLimitWait: 500,
        cache: false,
        transport: ( settings, onSuccess, onError ) =>
        {
            return $.ajax( settings )
                .done( ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) =>
                {
                    if ( data.length === 1 )
                    {
                        onError( jqXHR, 'abort', '' ); // Pretend the request failed
                        $field.val( data[0].code ) // Set the value in the input, don't use $field.typeahead('val', results[0].code);
                        $field.blur();
                        $field.trigger( 'typeahead:select', [ data[0] ] ); // Simulate the user selecting the option
                        return;
                    }

                    onSuccess( data, textStatus, jqXHR );
                } )
                .fail( onError );
        }
    }
} );

$field.typeahead(
    { /* .. options...*/ },
    {
        source: bloodhound,
    }
);
```